# Composite Primary Foreign Key on Spring Boot Data Repository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to establish a relation between two entities namely `Subscription` and `Delivery`. Both entities should use the id of the user as their primary key (i.e. both are in a one-to-one relationship with `User`, but `Delivery` only uses ids that are also present in `Subscription`). `Delivery` also uses the attribute email as an additional key (together with the user id to establish a composite primary key). While eclipselink, which I use as a jpa backend for spring boot, seems to be fine with this definition my application crashes when including the jpa repository with the following error message.

Error Message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected id attribute type [class com.tnt.entity.Subscription$DeliveryPK] on the existing id attribute [SingularAttributeImpl[EntityTypeImpl@482885994:Subscription [ javaType: class com.tnt.entity.Subscription descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.tnt.entity.Subscription --> [DatabaseTable(tbl_subscription)]), mappings: 6],org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[subscription]]] on the identifiable type [EntityTypeImpl@1615668218:Delivery [ javaType: class com.tnt.entity.Subscription$Delivery descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.tnt.entity.Subscription$Delivery --> [DatabaseTable(tbl_subscription_delivery)]), mappings: 2]] but found attribute type [class com.tnt.entity.Subscription].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.IdentifiableTypeImpl.getId(IdentifiableTypeImpl.java:204) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdMetadata.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:262) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Entities:

```
package com.tnt.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_subscription")
public class Subscription {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "daily_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveDailyReport;

    @Column(name = "weekly_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveWeeklyReport;

    @Column(name = "monthly_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveMonthlyReport;

    @Column(name = "multi_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean multiReport;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    public Subscription() {

    }

    public Subscription(User user){
        this.user = user;
        this.receiveDailyReport = true;
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_subscription_delivery")
    @IdClass(DeliveryPK.class)
    public static class Delivery {
        @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id")
        @ManyToOne
        @Id
        private Subscription subscription;

        @Column(name = "email")
        @Id
        private String email;

        public Delivery() {

        }

        public Delivery(Subscription subscription, String email){
            this.subscription = subscription;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public Subscription getSubscription() {
            return subscription;
        }

        public void setSubscription(Subscription subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscription;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        // ... equals, hashCode
    }

    public static class DeliveryPK implements Serializable {

        private Long subscription;

        private String email;

        public DeliveryPK() {
        }

        public Long getSubscription() {
            return subscription;
        }

        public void setSubscription(Long subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscription;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        // ... equals, hashCode
    }

    // ... getter, setter, equals, hashCode
}
```

Repository Interface:

```
interface DeliveryRepository : JpaRepository<Delivery, DeliveryPK> {
    @Query("SELECT d FROM Delivery d WHERE d.subscription = :subscription AND d.email = :email")
    fun findByEmail(subscription: Subscription, email: String): Optional<Delivery>
}
```

Has anybody got an idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** the question could also be asked differently - If I were to model this in SQL it would probably look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255),
    salt VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_subscription (
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_user(id),
    daily_report BOOLEAN,
    weekly_report BOOLEAN,
    monthly_report BOOLEAN,
    multi_report BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_subscription_delivery (
    subscription_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_subscription(user_id),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(email, subscription_id)
);
```

How can this behaviour be modeled in JPA 2.0?

Comment: What version of JPA are you using? PrimaryKeyJoinColumn on relationships was a v1 thing to do that was replaced with the MapsId annotation ( https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/index.html?javax/persistence/MapsId.html ) which makes it more clear which mapping controls the field.   You might try putting these entities and Pk class into their own java class files, as it is somehow confusing the PK class with the subscription class.

Comment: I am using Eclipselink version 2.7. I already tried the same with MapsId, but unfortunately got another error message: ```java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.IdAccessor cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor```

Comment: Whether you believe it or not, but dividing the classes into separate files did actually solve my problem

Comment: Something with the annotation processing in EclipseLink goes wrong, in oddly different ways, but usually revolving around the primary key. It was the bulk of my comment, and I just threw in the mapsID as an aside comment - it really will make your code easier IMO. With the primarykeyjoin column, I don't know that anyone really realizes which mapping actually sets the value in the database, and it leads to confusion as the subscription.id != subscription.user.id in many cases unless you are fixing things yourself.

Comment: So you intend to say that it is rather a problem of EclipseLink than me applying mapsid to the wrong attribute? Because simply adding mapsid to the user attribute in the subscription class does not do the job.

Comment: Yes, I should have broken them out as separate comments. MapsId comment was not a suggested solution to your current issue, but a general one to your provided code. Breaking up the Entities into their own class files was a comment for your particular situation - you can google this issue and it should come up as being raised in the past on the EclipseLink forms and email list. I went off vague memories not research, so wrote it out as something to try instead of a solution. Some do it and it works for them, but I suspect it only works if you don't use certain features like the metamodel

Comment: As I said, it worked for me as well - thanks for that. But I would like to write my code in the more "modern" way, so I would like to use MapsId. I just can't get to grips with where to put it that it actually works and I think I don't get what it does exactly. Please have a look at the comment below Brian Vosburghs answer as well.

Comment: Brian Vosburgh's code is what I was suggesting, and should work for you (now that you've broken out your classes into separate files). If it isn't, post another question with the code being used and the exception(s). MapsId is a straight replacement to the primarykeyjoinscolumn hack, allowing you to map the id field as both a basic and access it as a reference. I generally just mark relationships as IDs and do away with the basic mapping, but there are cases where I need to access an ID string and don't want to force fetching the entire referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

You can map `Subscription` with a single primary key relationship attribute:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_subscription")
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "daily_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveDailyReport;

    @Column(name = "weekly_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveWeeklyReport;

    @Column(name = "monthly_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveMonthlyReport;

    @Column(name = "multi_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean multiReport;
...
```

Alternatively, you can map `Subscription` with a `@MapsId` (hoping that this is not exactly the same as what you said in the comment above you have already tried : ) ):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_subscription")
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "daily_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveDailyReport;

    @Column(name = "weekly_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveWeeklyReport;

    @Column(name = "monthly_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean receiveMonthlyReport;

    @Column(name = "multi_report")
    @Basic
    private boolean multiReport;
...
```

Comment: I see your point but the problem is though, that the subscription entity already seems to be working. What causes the issue is the `Delivery` class. But again, it is working now besides the fact that it does not crash (i.e. throw a integrity constraint violation exception) if I insert 2 entries that are the same (but it doesn't insert them either).